# Subset in R by giving multiple names

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R which has a long list of company names. I want to select 4 of these companies. They are apple, microsoft, google, amazon. The column name of the company names is "name"

I am creating a subset with `subset(companies, name == c("apple", "microsoft", "google", "amazon"))`
But this returns 0 rows. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

This however works and returns one row.
`subset(companies, name == "apple")`

Comment: `subset(companies, name %in% c("apple", "microsoft", "google", "amazon"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `subset(companies, name %in% c("apple", "microsoft", "google", "amazon"))`.

The `%in%` operator works like SQL where is will look at each of your options provided `c("apple", "microsoft", "google", "amazon")` and compare each record to that list of options.

I ran a test sample with just changed to the `%in%` operator ,and it worked.